# Typo3: get level x page id from rootline for contextual menu

Tags: menu, line, typo3, root, typoscript

I have a page structure like this:

```
Page 1
 |-Page 1.1
 |  |-Page 1.1.1
 |  |-Page 1.1.2
 |-Page 1.2
 |  |-Page 1.2.1
 |  |-Page 1.2.2
Page2
etc.
```

I have 2 menus for this structure:

- Left menu - shows level 1 and level 2
- Top menu - shows only level 3

For example, when I am on page 1.1 of 1.1.1 or 1.1.2, the top menu should contain 1.1.1 and 1.1.2.

To create the top menu, I need to get the page id for level 2 from rootline.
Is there a way to get it in typoscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I understand your question you can just set the entry level for topmenu:

```
entryLevel = 1
```

Page 1 should be 0 in this example, so when you set the entry level to 1 for topmenu I think you should get the result you are looking for. (Or I'm missing something in the question)

Comment: you missed the fact that the top menu should be "contextual". so, 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 should appear when I'm on 1.1 or 1.1.1 or 1.1.2. With entryLevel = 1, I get 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.1 and 1.2.2.

Comment: I was not implementing this correctly, your answer is perfectly correct. Thank you, Florian!

Comment: Perfect, I was just writing a follow up with some more questions. You're welcome.